# Why am I unable to add MVC controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, controller, edmx

I'm pretty new to MVC. I've built an EDMX, successfully created the models and am now trying to go through scaffolding to build a controller. The first thing I notice is that in the Model Class dropdown, I have duplicates:

[image]

Now, "BillysRentals2" is the name of the project. I don't know where those extras are coming from or where these "Model classes" are stored. It's true I've had to re-do the adding of the ADO.NET Entity thing several times, but even after I completely delete the EDMX and all its contents, some of those model classes still remain, so which are the real ones and where are the others hiding?  It's confusing when you create "Model" and you're seeing "Model1" and stuff popping up.

But the second problem is that once I select a class, and press OK, I get this beautiful gem:

[image]

And yes, I tried removing the EDMX completely, doing a Re-build, removing and re-adding connections, Rebuilding again, and I'm still getting that message. What's wrong? I'm sure the fact that I'm getting multiple entries above means that there are bits and pieces of my previous efforts lying around someplace that are confusing MVC (not that it's hard to do) but how do I find them and get rid of them to start over?

And P.S. what is the difference anyway between a **model class** and a **data context class**?

Answer (score 0):

I had several metadata files leftover from the last time, which had field names that I didn't import this time around.